# Controlling string unescaping in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to load JSON data from Kafka into Clickhouse where the JSON contains some escape sequences. E.g:

```sql
:) SELECT JSONExtractRaw('{"message": "Hello \"to\" you!"}', 'message')

SELECT JSONExtractRaw('{"message": "Hello "to" you!"}', 'message')

┌─JSONExtractRaw('{"message": "Hello "to" you!"}', 'message')─┐
│ "Hello "                                                    │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

It appears that prior to calling `JSONExtractRaw`, the input strings are unescaped, which produces invalid JSON. The unescaping seems to be reproducible with this minimal example:

```sql
:) SELECT 'Hello \"there\"'

SELECT 'Hello "there"'

┌─'Hello "there"'─┐
│ Hello "there"   │
└─────────────────┘
```

I am wondering if it's possible to retain the original (escaped) representation of the input.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '{"message": "Hello \\"to\\" you!"}'

┌─'{"message": "Hello \\"to\\" you!"}'─┐
│ {"message": "Hello \"to\" you!"}     │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue of Clickhouse unescaping the string. Assuming you have no control of the input string, this solution is not applicable.
The question is whether it's possible to receive an input string and not apply unescaping to it.

Comment: Assume you need to charge a cellphone but you need to do it without a charger directly from electric socket.

Answer (score 0):

Let's test your case without CLI to emulate the table filled by data coming outside:

```sh
echo '{"message": "Hello \"to\" you!"}' | clickhouse-client \
    --password 12345 \
    --query="INSERT INTO test.json_001 SELECT json FROM input('json String') FORMAT CSV"
```

```sql
create database test;    
create table test.json_001 (json String) Engine=Memory;
```

Get required data:

```sh
clickhouse-client \
    --password 12345 \
    --query="SELECT JSONExtractRaw(json, 'message'), JSONExtractString(json, 'message') FROM test.json_001"

# result:
# "Hello \\"to\\" you!"   Hello "to" you!
```

```sql
SELECT
    JSONExtractRaw(json, 'message'),
    JSONExtractString(json, 'message')
FROM test.json_001

/* result
┌─JSONExtractRaw(json, 'message')─┬─JSONExtractString(json, 'message')─┐
│ "Hello \"to\" you!"             │ Hello "to" you!                    │
└─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

It works as it should. I don't see any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am running into an issue when trying to run one of the commands...

$ echo '{"message": "Hello \"to\" you!"}' | clickhouse-client --host clickhouse --query="INSERT INTO test.json_001 SELECT json FROM input('json String') FORMAT CSV"

Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 65: FORMAT CSV. Expected one of: table, table function, subquery or list of joined tables, AS, SETTINGS, FINAL, SAMPLE, JOIN, INNER, PREWHERE, WHERE, WITH, HAVING, LIMIT, alias, UNION ALL, identifier, ORDER BY, array join, LEFT ARRAY JOIN, ARRAY JOIN, GROUP BY

Comment: What version of ClickHouse do you use? It looks like it is not older *19.15.2.2 from 2019-10-01*; *input*-table function was added in this version (https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/changelog/#clickhouse-release-19-15-2-2-2019-10-01).

Comment: I'm on 20.X, so I'd have thought it'd be available. Regardless, I was able to resolve my issue (and you were correct that nothing was wrong). My issue was due to String sequences or TSVs being unescaped implicitly by Clickhouse. I resorted to loading the data as CSV (with an empty delimiter) which for some reason does not unescape the data. I can then run JSONExtractX on the data.